# Display Spring WebFlow Global Transitions

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-webflow

I am a new at using Spring Webflow. I am trying to use Global transitions. In my jsp I am trying to display all the transitions using

```
<c:forEach var="transition" items="${flowRequestContext.currentState.transitions}">     
<c:out value="${transition.id}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

I can see all the transitions for the currentState but I cannot see the global transitions.

My understanding was the global transitions would be available in all the view-states. To get the global transitions do I need to access it in a different way?

Here is a simplified version of my flow xml

```
<flow xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"    
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

<view-state id="state1" view="view1.jsp" model="person">
    <transition on="submit" to="state2"/>
    <transition on="cancel" to="canceled"/>
</view-state>

<view-state id="state2" view="view1.jsp" model="person">
    <transition on="complete" to="complete"/>
</view-state>

<view-state id="canceled" view="view1.jsp" model="person">
    <transition on="resubmit" to="resubmit"/>
</view-state>

<action-state id="reassign">
    <evaluate expression="CustomAction.reassign(flowRequestContext)"/>
</action-state>

<end-state id="complete"/>

<global-transitions>    
    <transition on="cancel" to="canceled"/>
    <transition on="reassign" to="reassign"/>
</global-transitions>

</flow>
```

So when in state1 in the jsp how canI display all the tranistions including global?

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never.
There is a getGlobalTransitionSet method, but it's in the implementation org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow class, not in the interface FlowDefinition. This method returns a TransitionSet that is not iterable by forEach, but fortunatelly it has a toArray method.

If you feel comfortable with this, you could use:

```
${flowRequestContext.activeFlow.globalTransitionSet.toArray()}
```

Tested.